# Solaris Zones - Prevent Zone from Booting

Tags: solaris, zones

I have a server with a master zone and 4 'child' zones. I now only need master + 1 zone, but cannot simply delete the unneeded zones.

At the moment the unneeded zones are shut down and show inactive. However, if the server reboots, then all 4 zones start up again.

Is there a way to preserve a zone but prevent it from booting when the server starts (i.e. manual boot only)?

Added: the command must be reversible. The best option would be a command that stopped auto-boot of zones but still allowed manual boot (i.e. "zoneadm -z zone boot" would still work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The zone has a property 'autoboot' which if set to true will cause the zone to boot whenever the server (master zone) is booted. To stop this automatic booting of the zone, set autoboot to false:

zonecfg -z "zone" 
set autoboot=false 
info 
verify 
commit 
exit

Now the zone won't boot automatically when the machine boots.

Answer (score 1):

[Mark the zone as unavailable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37628/goapy.html):

> In Oracle Solaris, the zone state unavailable, indicates that the zone is installed but cannot be booted. ...

For example:

```
zoneadm -z name mark unavailable
```